# How to make an css image source transition on clicking on a hamburger item in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have an hamburger icon, on clicking on that, the image changes. I need to show transition on the images.

code looks like this::

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

function handleClck = () => {
 setIsOpen(true);
}
function getImage = () => {
  isOpen ? <img src={url1} className="xxxxxuxu" /> : <img src={url2} className="yyyyyyyy" /> ;
}

<div class="nav">
      <div class="hamburger" onClick={handleClck}></div>
      {getImage()}
</div>
```

I want to show the css transition between image changes.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although images can't be animated like the way you are seeking for, but we can use a hack. The hack is - adding a fading animation when the image changes.

In the below snippet, there is an example of the effect -

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector(".img1").classList.add("t1");
document.querySelector(".img1").src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80";
}, 2000);
```

```css
.img1{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

@keyframes fade{ /*The animation*/
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.t1{ /*The class which has animation*/
  animation: fade 1 2s; /*Animation will only run once*/
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="img1" />
```

Most of the code in above snippet is just for demonstration purpose, but in you app, you can add the class while changing the image -

```
function getImage = () => {
  isOpen ? <img src={url1} className="t1" /> : <img src={url2} className="t1" /> ;
}
```

Where t1 is the css class which has the animation attached.

Although I am not a react guy, but I believe that the code should work for your react app as well.